# Need clarity in Python regarding keyword argument

Tags: python, oop, keyword-argument

I am not clear here:

```
class Duck:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self._color=kwargs.get('color','white')

def main():
    donald=Duck(feet=2)
    print(donald._color) #it will print white
```

Questions:

1. Is `self._color` a variable or dictionary here?
2. How to get the value of `feet` here? Using `print(donald._color['feet'])` results in an error.

Comment: `_color` is not a dictionary here. It would still be a variable if it *was* a dictionary, however.

Comment: then what happens to donald=Duck(feet=2)? Where is this feet=2 gets stored if it is not dictionary

Comment: It is ignored. It is a key in the `kwargs` dictionary that you are otherwise not using in your code. The `kwargs` dictionary is just a local variable in your `__init__` function, you never assign other attributes based on it or its contents.

Comment: and how to print the value of 'feet' using object donald?

Comment: @eTarun you can't, as the example stands, as `kwargs` is discarded at the end of `Duck.__init__`. The `2` isn't stored anywhere within the instance.

Comment: thanks Martijn Pieters , jonrsharpe. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `kwargs` dictionary is a *local variable* in your `__init__` method, and it is a dictionary. You are mostly ignoring it in your code, and when the method ends, the dictionary is discarded again.

The only thing you do with the dictionary, is to retrieve one value from it given a key, and if that key is not present, substitute a default value. `kwargs.get('color', 'white')` returns `'white'` because the `'color'` key is not present. Thus, `self._color` is bound to the string `'white'`, not to a dictionary.

Note that the term *variable* is another way of referencing to *names* here, `kwargs` is a variable for example. Depending on who you ask, variables can also refer to attributes on Python objects, so `self._color` is a variable, regardless of what you refer to with it. `'white'` is a string object here, but you can also assign a dictionary to it.

Your code never looks for other keys, so the `'feet'` key in `kwargs` goes unnoticed and is discarded again with the `kwargs` dictionary.

If you wanted to do anything with `feet`, then you'd have to retrieve *that* from your dictionary. For example:

```
if 'feet' in kwargs:
     self._feet = kwargs['feet']
```

This sets `self._feet` **only** if the keyword argument was given. If no `feet` keyword argument was passed in, then the `_feet` attribute is never set either.

You could give it a default value instead; either by setting a class attribute with the same name (it'll be used if the instance doesn't have a `_feet` attribute), or by using the same `dict.get()` method to return a default value instead.

Comment: Or, if `self._feet` has a sensible default, do `self._feet = kwargs.get('feet', 'sensible default')`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: or set a class attribute. Or set it explicitly to a default first, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Q1. It's a variable.

Two interesting things are happening here.

1. **kwargs in the argument of the method.  This means you can call `Duck` and pass in any named argument, such as `Duck(color='red')`, `Duck(name='Scrooge')`, `Duck(sound='quack')`.  That info is going to be temporarily inserted in the dictionary `kwarg`.  If I were to do

`scrooge = Duck(name='Scrooge', sound='quack', color='red')`

then `kwarg` will look like `{'name':'Scrooge', 'sound':'quack', 'color':'red'}`,  See for yourself by inserting `print kwargs` in your `__init__` method.

2. `kwarg.get('color', 'white')` asks if `Duck` got called with a named argument `color='something'`.  If so, that something gets assigned to self._color.  If kwargs does not have the 'color' key, then 'white' is used as the default value and gets assigned to `self._color`.  This 'ask if a dict has key x, if so return the associated value, if not return this default value y' is what `dictionary.get(x, y)` does.

Q2. The value of feet is lost.  `Duck` accepts the value when instantiating the object, but does nothing with it during intiallization, so it's not assigned as `donald`'s member variable.  The local variable `kwarg` disappears when the `__init__` method ends, and only things assigned to `self.xxx` persist.